# Are SQL Server's Date values stored as a single int?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server stores `DATETIME` internally as two `INT` values, as [SQLDenis explains](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server).

Is it correct (by logical extension) that `DATE` types (SQL Server 2008+) are stored as a *single* `INT`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for fun, let's see what's on the page.

```
CREATE DATABASE floob;
GO
USE floob;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.experiment(d DATE NOT NULL);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.experiment(d);
INSERT dbo.experiment SELECT SYSDATETIME();

DBCC IND('floob', 'dbo.experiment', 1);
```

Partial results (will differ on your system a bit):

```
----
13

PagePID iam_chain_type PageType
------- -------------- --------
229     In-row data    10
228     In-row data    1
```

So let's look at page 228:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604, -1);
DBCC PAGE(13, 1, 228, 3);
```

Partial results. We see that the value for d occupies 3 bytes. If we look at the memory dump for the row, we see a hex value for the internal storage component: `c8350b02` - what could that be?

[image]

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, '0001-01-01'), CONVERT(DATE, '2012-06-11'));
```

Result:

```
734664
```

So:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), 734664);
```

Result:

```
0x000B35C8
```

(Looks amazingly similar to what's on the page, just with bits flipped in the opposite order?)

Then:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT, 0x000B35C8), CONVERT(DATE, '0001-01-01'))
```

Result:

```
2012-06-11
```

Comment: Hmm but what about the time part?

Comment: @Azimuth The question was about `date` which doesn't have a time part.